# jQuery - Building a tree style list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

My DOM is as follows

```
<ul>
    <li id="Browse">
        Browse
        <ul id="browse-one">
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery in a  in the bottom of the page is:

```
$("#Browse").click(function() {
     $("#browse-one").html('<div class="ui-widget">Loading...</div>');
     $("#browse-one").load('../api/browse.php?do=getFirst');
});
```

This script goes into the database and spits out raw LIs.  After this runs the DOM is modified as follows

```
<ul>
    <li id="Browse">
        Browse
        <ul id="browse-one">
            <li id="one-1" data-id="1">SOMETHING</li>
            <li id="one-2" data-id="2">SOMETHING</li>
            <li id="one-3" data-id="3">SOMETHING</li>
            <li id="one-4" data-id="4">SOMETHING</li>
            .
            .
            .
            <li id="one-N" data-id="N">SOMETHING</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What is the proper jqueryish way to track clicks on these LIs.  I want to extract the data-id of the clicked element and make a second API call to construct part two of the tree.  For example if data-id="1"'s LI is clicked the DOM should be:

```
<ul>
    <li id="Browse">
        Browse
        <ul id="browse-one">
            <li id="one-1" data-id="1">SOMETHING
                <ul id="Something Here">
                    <li id="two-1" data-id="1">HMM</li>
                    <li id="two-2" data-id="2">HMM</li>
                    <li id="two-3" data-id="3">HMM</li>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    <li id="two-M" data-id="M">HMM</li>     
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="one-2" data-id="2">SOMETHING</li>
            <li id="one-3" data-id="3">SOMETHING</li>
            <li id="one-4" data-id="4">SOMETHING</li>
            .
            .
            .
            <li id="one-N" data-id="N">SOMETHING</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Im having trouble thinking of how i'de keep each of the inner UL's IDs unique.  Sure I can do the "LEVEL-ID" as in "two-1" but I feel this is hackish and not the proper jquery way.

EDIT:

But now how do I track the children's clicks??  This doesn't seem valid but I hope you understand wht I'm trying to do

```
$("#Browse").click(function() {
     $("#locations-browse").html('<div class="ui-widget">Loading...</div>');
     $("#locations-browse").load('../api/browse.php?do=getFirst');

     //Child is tracked
     $("#locations-browse").delegate("li","click",function(evt){
        var inner = $(this).append("<ul></ul>");
        inner.html('<div class="ui-widget">Loading...</div>');
        inner.load('../api/browse.php?do=getSecond');

        $(this).delegate("li","click", function(evt) {
            alert("Child ". $(this).data("id") . " is clicked";
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT 2:

Hmm this still is not working:

```
$("#Browse").click(function() {
     $("#locations-browse").html('<div class="ui-widget">Loading...</div>');
     $("#locations-browse").load('../api/browse.php?do=getFirst');

     //Child is tracked
     $("#locations-browse").delegate("li","click",function(evt){
        $(this).append("<ul></ul>");
        $(this).children("ul").load('../api/browse.php?do=getSecond?location-id='.$(this).data("id"));

        $(this).delegate("li","click", function(evt) {
            alert($(this).data("id"));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the event via `li#Browse` and reference the `data-id` attribute relative to the event's contextual element.

```
$('#Browse').on('click', 'li', function(evt) {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Incidentally, there's several out-of-the-box plugins that do what you need, just in case you didn't want to build you own, e.g. [YUI Treeview](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/) or the [one I wrote](http://www.mitya.co.uk/scripts/XML-Tree---visualise-and-traverse-your-XML-186#tree0:0;).

Comment: Children as in the `li` tags - branches - of the tree? That's what my answer allows. It will even fire for `li` tags that are not yet in the tree and may be loaded in at a later point. That's one of the positive side-effects of event delegation.

Comment: Please see my new edits.  The second load is not being fired.  Also whenever an internal LI is clicked the main locations--browse.load() is fired again.